# What's the best way to run a laravel project with out using artisan serve?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

guys I have a laravel project and its working fine. Every time I start the project by typing the command `php artisan serve` and then by typing the url `localhost:8000` in my browser. But now I want to start my project only by typing the url `localhost/projectname`.

So I did a little bit of digging and found out a way to do this, I made it possible by changing the server.php file from root directory to index.php and copying the htaccess file from public folder to root directory`. This way my browser loaded only html file or php file but css files and js files were not loaded so I had to modify there link on the blade file for example:

**Previously a style.css file was linked as:**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('front_end/assets/css/style.css')}}">
```

**Now I link the same style.css file as below:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('/public/front_end/assets/css/style.css')}}">
```

And It works fine.

But now I have found another problem, I have stored some files (images) in the the `storage/app/public/myfolder` directory so to access the files I had to use the command `php artisan storage:link` command and to access the files(images) from above mentioned directory from blade file I use the code below:

```
<img src="{{$url = Storage::url('myfolder/'.$company->logo_name)}}">
```

This code did worked only worked when I used to start my project using `php artisan serve` command. Now I its not linking so what should I do? And also can you guys tell me the way that I changed the `server.php` file to `index.php` is the right way or not? And what you guys do in your real projects?

Thank You.

Comment: You don't need to mess around too much for it to work, just create a virtualhost e.g: ``projectname.app`` add it to your hosts file and access it like any website ... just be sure to add the public folder as the document root for this virtualhost

Comment: Thanks I created virtualhost file and now I am able to access it like website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deploying a Laravel project you want your `nginx` or `apache` configuration to point to your `public` path of your project. Changing the `server.php` or `index.php` files are not necessary.

#### Apache Config Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName project.dev
   DocumentRoot "/home/vagrant/projects/project/public"
   <Directory "/home/vagrant/projects/project/public">
      AllowOverride all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see with this `apache` config example, it points to the public directory of your project.

You can achieve this locally by installing either `Apache` or `nginx` on your local machine.

I would recommend following Laravel's documentation guide on using Vagrant's Homestead to get an idea of how this is working before you decide to run this on a server. [A link here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead)

There is a couple of options you can take to achieve essentially the same goal. This depends on the machine you are running on and personal preference.

- [Laravel Valet for Mac](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/valet)
- [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead)
- [WAMP for Windows](https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp)
- [MAMP for Mac](https://www.mamp.info/en/)

Comment: Laravel clearly indicates to NOT be put elsewhere than directly under the root directory (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#directory-configuration). So if one puts Laravel directly under the root directory `/home/XYZ/project` as recommanded by the Laravel docs AND if one changes Apache to point `/home/XYZ/project/public` according to your solution (which sets the root directory), then the server will return error 500 or other error. Am I right? If yes: is there any other Apache configuration option to set only the `public` directory (not the root directory)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify any file.

You need one of this:

- Web server installed locally, Apache or Nginx
- A Vagrant Virtual machine for running the project like in production environemnts like [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead)
- [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/valet)

If you decide to go with Web Server, you just need to consider to point to `project/public` folder instead of `project`.

Doing with one of this options, you won't need to modify the assets url, since `public` shouldn't be part of your url in any case.

Comment: Laravel clearly indicates to NOT be put elsewhere than directly under the root directory (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#directory-configuration). So if one puts Laravel directly under the root directory `/home/XYZ/project` as recommanded by the Laravel docs AND if one changes Apache to point `/home/XYZ/project/public` according to your solution (which sets the root directory), then the server will return error 500 or other error. Am I right? If yes: is there any other Apache configuration option to set only the `public` directory (not the root directory)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't do any tweaks in server.php file, it's fine.
To run your project with url like, http://localhost/my-project.dev or simply my http://project.dev, use WAMP or XAMPP (if working on a windows machine) and lamp for linux. You can also checkout Laravel's Homestead.

Then setup virtual host.
See [this](http://www.coderomeos.org/how-to-set-up-virtual-host-on-wamp-server) tutorial for setting up virtual host on WAMP - http://www.coderomeos.org/how-to-set-up-virtual-host-on-wamp-server

And don't put your assets in public/assets folder to prevent using storage link.